# Transform classic formula to a dynamic array formula

Tags: excel-formula, dynamic-arrays

I'm trying to transform my clasic formula to a dynamic array one, but i can't

My current working classic formula is

```
=LET(
per; B4;    
data; FILTER(CHOOSE({1\2}; Taula1[Cap];Taula1[Cap]*Taula1[Tipo]); Taula1[Per]=per);    
res; SUM(INDEX(data;;2)) / SUM(INDEX(data;;1) );
res)
```

But it doesn't run when i'm trying to transform the formula changing the parameter to a dynamic array **B4#**

Now I copy/paste the classic formula to next rows

The result must be:

[image: Final image]

And source data was:

[image: Source data]

Comment: Not sure may be something like this would work: `=LET(
         per, B4#,
         data, FILTER(CHOOSE({1,2,3}, Taula1[Per],Taula1[Cap],Taula1[Cap]*Taula1[Tipo]), ISNUMBER(XMATCH(Taula1[Per],per))),
         uniq,UNIQUE(INDEX(data,,1)),
         rowwise,BYROW(uniq,LAMBDA(x,SUM(--(x=INDEX(data,,1))*(INDEX(data,,3)))/SUM(--(x=INDEX(data,,1))*(INDEX(data,,2))))),
         HSTACK(uniq,rowwise))`

Answer (score 1):

Excelent !!!

```
=LET(per; B4#;
     rowwise; BYROW(per; LAMBDA(x; SUM(--(x=Taula1[Per])*(Taula1[Cap])*(Taula1[Tipo]) ) / SUM(--(x=Taula1[Per])*(Taula1[Cap])) ));
     res; HSTACK(per; rowwise);
     res)
```

I didn't have enough experience with BYROW function

Thanks a lot

Comment: This really nice, i was thinking about making it short, but due to very less information i was not able to think more, also you had not responded in the mean time, ok, since you have resolved it ensure to accept your own answer so it helps someone in the future.